# How to turn specific values of a column into NAs based on the condition of a letter existing in another column?

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, multiple-columns, na

I have this example df

```
df = data.frame(id = c('1E','1F','2E','2F','3F','4F'),
                statut = c('A','A','B','B','A','A') )
```

For each id that has the number repeated, I wish that the statut becomes NA when the letter of the repeated id is E

I am looking to have the following output:

```
  id statut
1 1E   <NA>
2 1F      A
3 2E   <NA>
4 2F      B
5 3F      A
6 4F      A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a set of conditions that match your expected output:

```r
idx <- substr(df$id, 1, 1) == dplyr::lead(substr(df$id, 1, 1)) & substr(df$id, 2, 2) == "E"
df$statut[idx] <- NA

  id statut
1 1E   <NA>
2 1F      A
3 2E   <NA>
4 2F      B
5 3F      A
6 4F      A
```

Or in a more dplyr friendly pipeline:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  separate_wider_regex(id, c(number = "\\d+", letter = ".*")) %>% 
  group_by(number) %>% 
  mutate(statut = ifelse(n() > 1 & letter == "E", NA, statut))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Let's say that some of the ids have numbers like 10 or 100. How can I handle that ?

Comment: you could use `separate_wider` instead for a safer parsing, check edit

Answer (score 2):

My personal preference in such cases is to use `data.table` for its efficiency and simplicity.

```
library(data.table)

# Set the data.frame to data.table
setDT(df)

# Use ifelse to test the condition if the last character in every single value
# in id is E or not, and if yes, replace it with NA
df[ , statut := ifelse(substr(id, 2, 2), NA, statut)]
```

Another solution would be to use logical grep to do the same:

```
df[ , statut := ifelse(grepl("E", id), NA, statut)]
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Compact solution with `str_detect`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(statut = ifelse(str_detect(id, "E"), NA, statut))
```

Alternatively, you can first `extract` the digit and the letter in `id` and then set `E` to `NA`:

```
df %>%
  extract(id, into = c("id_n", "id_g"), regex = "(.)(.)", remove = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(statut = na_if(id_g, "E")) %>%
  select(-c(matches("_")))
```